Spring Controller - in case of invalid URL fixed and redirect in a clean code way
Valid URL:
/username-01/posts/703fa464-3ed0-451a-9687-bdefc9e41847

Invalid URL:
/xxxxxxxxxxx/posts/703fa464-3ed0-451a-9687-bdefc9e41847

The request URL can come with an invalid username, because meanwhile the post owner may have changed their username. So if that happen I would like to redirect the client to the right URL. The username is not really needed but I want to keep to have consistency in my URLs.
The following code works, but not sure if it is the most appropiate way:
I have the following GET @RestController:
@GetMapping("/{urlUsername}/{id}")
PostDto get(@PathVariable String urlUsername, @PathVariable UUID id) {
    var post = service.get(id);
    if (post == null)
        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    if (!urlUsername.equals(post.username())) {
        throw new MovedPermanentlyException(post.url());
    }
    return post;
}
record PostDto(UUID id, String message, String username) {
    public String url() {
        return String.format("/%s/posts/%s", username, id);
    }
}

and here I handle the MovedPermanentlyException:
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomControllerExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(MovedPermanentlyException.class)
    ResponseEntity<String> handle(MovedPermanentlyException ex) {
        return ResponseEntity //
                .status(HttpStatus.MOVED_PERMANENTLY) //
                .header(HttpHeaders.LOCATION, ex.url()).build();
    }
}

I know I can use the ResponseEntity in the controller, and get rid off the MovedPermanentlyException, but I think this makes a mess in the controller method.
I know throwing a ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.MOVED_PERMANENTLY) will send a 301 code response, but it would miss the location Header.
I know this code will not work but I would like to do something like this. I think the code would result very clean:
var location = post.url();
throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.MOVED_PERMANENTLY, location);

Then I would like that where Spring handles the ResponseStatusException would detect the HttpStatus.MOVED_PERMANENTLY and location, and add the location header to the response.
